# JMS message priority not working on Message

Tags: jms

I need to set message priority so that high priority messages are consumed before low priority messages by receivers.

First I tried with `message.setJMSPriority()` method to set the priority, but it was not working with any JMS broker I've tried (e.g. HornetQ and ActiveMQ) so finally I set the priority of the `MessageProducer` using `setPriority()` method, and it works fine now.

Why isn't `Messsge.setJMSPriority()` working in any of the JMS vendor implementations, and why do we need to set the priority of the producer not the message itself to set the priority of the message? What is the use of `Messsge.setJMSPriority()` method then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer this question all you need to do is read the API docs for the setJMSPriority method and it tells you why.  Here's the relevant text.

> Sets the priority level for this message.
>
> JMS providers set this field when a message is sent. This method can be used to change the value for a message that has been received.

The JMS Provider (ActiveMQ, HornetMQ, etc) set the priority in the producer on send to either the default value of 4, or to whatever value you've set the producer to use, so setting the value before send on the message itself won't have any effect.

Answer (score 12):

The following *will not work*:

```
msg.setJMSPriority(9); // Not working!
```

In this code, the message priority is set to 9, indicating this is a high-priority message.
However, when the message is sent, the message will have a priority of 4 (normal
priority). The reason? Like the message expiration, the JMS provider will look at the
message priority property on the sender, or on the send(..) invocation, and then invoke the setJMSPriority on the message method prior
to placing the message on the queue. Since the default message priority is 4 (normal
priority), the message priority will not be set to a high priority message, as the developer had originally intended.

Like the message expiration, there are two ways of setting the message priority: you
can invoke the setPriority() method on the MessageProducer (QueueSender or Topic
Publisher) or set the message priority when sending the message:

```
//set the default message priority for all messages to 9 (high)
QueueSender qSender = qSession.createSender(requestQ);
qSender.setPriority(9);

qSender.send(msg1);
//this message is low priority
qSender.send(msg2, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, 1, 30000);
```

In this example, msg1 will be sent with a priority of 9 (high priority), whereas msg2 will
be sent with a priority of 1 (low priority).

Answer (score 7):

This is a JMS Specification requirement.

You should change the priority on the Message Producer.

Comment: It's required that the API has this method that tricks you into thinking it does something, while actually doing nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You can read JmsTemplate http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

Some JMS providers allow the setting of default QOS values administratively through the configuration of the ConnectionFactory.
Check isExplicitQosEnabled property.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Artemis Apache MQ with Spring Boot and here is my solution.

1. Add following to your configuration class ` @Bean
   public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

   ```
   JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
   jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
   jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
   return jmsTemplate;
   ```

   }`
2. In your Message producer before sending message add following

   jmsTemplate.setPriority(1); //or whatever your priorities are
3. Enjoy message prioritization